# How to pass multiple arguments with pipe symbol into a bash-script's case statement

Tags: bash, escaping, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I have a script that organizes files in my downloads directory according to their filetype.

```
function moveto {
    for filename in *
    do
    case "${filename##*.}" in
        $1 ) echo "!";; # echo statement for debugging
    esac
    done
}
```

I have a .png file in my downloads directory and nothing else.
When I call `moveto "png"`, the exclamation mark appears.
When I call `moveto "png|jpg"`, the exclamation mark **doesn't** appear.
When I simply type `png|jpg` into the case statement, using no variables, the exclamation mark appears.

I've tried changing things up more than a few ways; using single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, aliases, etc., nothing seems to work. Would be great if someone could help out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>|</kbd> in a `case` statement is part of the syntax of the case statement, so it must be part of the source code. (The same is true of the <kbd>)</kbd> terminating the pattern list.)

You can get the effect you want by enabling extended globs (`shopt -s extglob`) and then using one:

```
moveto "@(png|jpg)"
```

Extended glob patterns are documented in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching); they consist of one of the characters <kbd>*</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd>, or <kbd>!</kbd> followed by a parenthesized list of patterns separated by <kbd>|</kbd>. The initial character meanings are mostly familiar:

```
* zero or more repetitions of any of the patterns
+ one or more repetitions of any of the patterns
? nothing or exactly one of the patterns
@ exactly one of the patterns
! does not match any of the patterns
```

If you wanted to get fancy, you could assemble the pattern yourself:

```
moveto() {
  local pattern="@($(tr ' ' '|'<<<"$*"))"
  local filename
  for filename in *; do
    case "${filename##*.}" in
      $pattern) echo "!";; # echo statement for debugging
    esac
  done
}

moveto png jpg
```